# Troubles with black american slang - what does "yellow bones" mean?

Tags: american-english, slang

I'm stuck with some troubles. I've just watched videos on YouTube and found [Trevor Noah on "Naw Mean?"](https://youtu.be/A4qGi8p47Sw?t=26s). At 00:00:26 that guy starts to make a parody of black American slang, and I can't understand what he says. Could someone explain, why that guy named Trevor "B"? And what does "yellow bone" mean in this context? Because books don't teach us that kind of speaking.

Comment: @ColleenV how can I ask more specific question about this text if I don't even hear words he says? It's a pity.

Comment: I'm sorry but this may not be the right site for what you want. Look over the information in the [help] to get a better idea. In general, we want to build a library of questions that are of use to other folks, not just help one person at a time.

Comment: It's honestly not worth translating or understanding what he says... part of what makes it funny is that it's not understandable... and that's the joke.

Comment: I understand all of it, but I think it is a little too broad a question.  @Bringoff's difficulty understanding probably comes from a combination of the pronunciation, the slang vocabulary and the grammar.  Given how long the clip is, it would take too much to parse all of it.  ....

Comment: For instance, where do you start on the first two sentences:   _"Hey yo B, let me holler at you for a minute, man, let me holler at you. Man, I ain't even gonna front, I ain't  gonna front.   I came out here, dude, I didn't even know who you was.  Yo man, I didn't even know they got those yellow bones out there in the mother land, yo."_

Comment: I wouldn't regard this as a "transcription request;" and I strongly disagree that it's "not about learning English." That said, I can see why this would be hard to answer. This question reminds me of the famous ["I speak jive"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdCjbJ6NEfc) scenes from the movie _Airplane_. I think the comment by @Catija explains it quite well; the routine is funny because even most native speakers would have trouble following it.

Comment: @Adam thank you! Could I ask you for some explanations? What did he mean when says "yellow bones"? And why did he name him "B"?

Comment: "Yellow bones" are  African Americans with very light skin.  I WOULD NEVER USE THIS TERM.  You shouldn't either.  I don't normally recommend Urban Dictionary, but in this case, it is probably a reasonable place to start for terms like **B**: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=b  and **Front** http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=front  Whenever you use Urban Dictionary, be mindful of the number of votes that answers have, and don't assume that 24 upvotes means that you can use the word with all/any native speakers.  Slang can be highly regional.

Comment: the urban dictionary is a great resource for a comprehensive list of slang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["Yellow bones"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=yellow+bone) is an African American colloquial expression referring to an African American woman with unusually light colored skin.